# helmholtz free energy of a polymer

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, polymers

You have a polymer chain of $N$ units, which is represented by $N$ independent springs in series. The springs are Hookean, with spring constant $L$, and the end to end vector is $\mathbf r$. So the energy of the spring is $$\frac{L\mathbf r\cdot\mathbf r}{2}.$$

Neglect kinetic energy contributions. There is one state per volume $W$ in $\mathbf r$-space.

Calculate the Helmholtz free energy of the polymer (you need to integrate over all possible values of the three-component end to end spring vectors.)

I have no idea how to set this up, what three integrals? How do they lead to the free energy?

Comment: What university do you study at?

Comment: UDel, why do you ask?

Comment: you wouldn't happen to know how to approach this, would you?

Comment: because kinetic energy is being neglected, this isn't a random stepping problem - so i don't know how to approach it

Comment: I just asked because some of the questions were similar to what I remember from uni.

Comment: where did you go?

Comment: one in Australia

Comment: ah...well i guess a stat mech class is a stat mech class. i'm an undergrad still, understand the concepts and the chemistry, but i tend to get lost when it comes to setting certain things up. but then i can follow it

Comment: i've got this question and one other one posted: "energy and number of configurations for particular microstate." if you're willing to help i would truly appreciate it